# Preserve data during the login process-redirect in Laravel 4

Tags: authentication, laravel-4, preserve

I am creating a comments section in my site, and I want logged-in users only to be able to add comments. However, not logged-in ones can write them and click on the "add" button.

If the user is not logged-in, the laravel´s `'before' => 'auth'` filter takes the user to the login page, then the sign in process starts and finally (assuming a successfully logged in process) laravel redirects to the "intended" route, but using the "get" method.

How can I preserve my data (The comment) so that I can store it (or at least show it again to the user) after user gets logged in?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve that>

If the user is logged-in, the system uses this route>

```
Route::post('/account/addComment',array(
        'as'    =>  'account-add-comment-post',
        'uses'  =>  'CallCenterController@postAddComment'
));
```

If the user is not logged-in, I simple use this one>

```
Route::get('/account/sign-in/{data}',array(
    'as'    =>  'accont-sign-in-data',
    'uses'  =>  'CallCenterController@postAddComment'
));
```

The controller is the same, with just one adjusment, the function Redirect::back() wont work since "back" is diferent for eachone, so giving a specific url using Redirect::to(url); the job is done...